# Children json elements Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

Json code works fine if i call pages with `{{result.title}}` but if i want to call to the children of `author`, json elements does not work

**Controller**

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
     $http.get('post.json')
     .then(function (response){
          console.log(response.data);
          $scope.results = response.data.pages,
          $scope.resultauthor = response.data.author;
     });
```

**Json Example**

```
 {
 "pages": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "type": "page",
      "modified": "2016-08-09 17:28:01",
      "categories": [],
      "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "admin",
        "description": ""
    },
}
```

**Html**

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in resultauthor">
    {{ item.name }}
    </div>
```

where am I going wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you certain that your `$http.get` is returning an object that contains `author`? Given the sample json that you have provided, it looks like `author` is a child of the objects in the `pages` array.

Comment: Hi Lex, the sample json It is above the comments It is stored in the file "post.json"

Comment: So `$scope.resultauthor` is always going to be undefined. Although, I don't understand how `{{result.title}}` would work because you don't show a `$scope.result` variable and the sample json you provided does not have a `title` property anywhere. Maybe you should edit your question to provide a [MCVE] and then better suggestions can be provided.

Comment: here plunker plnkr.co/edit/2x177MlVq1RSLIemriQ5?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `resultsauthor` to `resultauthor`.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in resultauthor">
    {{ item.name }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the `json` you provided `response.data.author` will not exist.
You first need to retrieve a `page` item from the pages array and then get the author of that specific element:

```
$http.get('post.json')
.then(function (response){
  $scope.results = response.data.pages;
});
```

Besides that, try to check in your console if there is any networking or javascript error to give you a better feedback.

**UPDATE**

You are also using `ng-repeat` in a wrong way (you need to iterate an array not an object to get the expected behavior).

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in results">
  {{ item.author }}
 </div>
```

Check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/I6jO6djpk8ZJpRVIeWtY?p=preview) plunkr.

Comment: does not work not error on my console, you can see it here http://plnkr.co/edit/2x177MlVq1RSLIemriQ5?p=preview

Comment: @max Actually is working: the problem is that you are using the ng for in an object so the the behaviour is not as you think. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but `author` is not an array - it's an object. If you want to loop through the properties of `author` then you need to use `(key, value) for object` syntax in your `ng-repeat`. Here is an example (I had to just assign the json data directly to a `$scope` property since the inline snippets don't support external files like your `post.json` file).

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.results = [{
    "id": 2,
    "type": "page",
    "modified": "2016-08-09 17:28:01",
    "categories": [],
    "tags": [],
    "title": "Title",
    "author": {
      "id": 1,
      "slug": "admin",
      "name": "admin",
      "first_name": "",
      "last_name": "",
      "nickname": "admin",
      "url": "",
      "description": ""
    }
  }];
  $scope.resultauthor = $scope.results[0].author;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in resultauthor">
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="result in results">
    <p>{{ result.title }}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: He is using for $scope.resultauthor in ng-repeat, I am wondering how does it make sense cause $scope.resultauthor is not an array.

Comment: Exactly. Which is why I pointed out that very thing in my answer and provided an example of looping the object's properties and values.